# How to make Getter Setter Function per each members with tp_getset in python c api?

Tags: c++, cpython

i'm using python c api to bind my class in c++.
The PyTypeObject struct has tp_getset member which can register python class(type)'s member with it's getter setter function.

tp_getset is PyGetSetDef type.

```
typedef PyObject *(*getter)(PyObject *, void *);
typedef int (*setter)(PyObject *, PyObject *, void *);

typedef struct PyGetSetDef {
    char *name;
    getter get;
    setter set;
    char *doc;
    void *closure;
} PyGetSetDef;
```

And get set function will use for this. (python code)

```
test = ModuleName.TestObject()

#setter will called!
test.member = 10

#getter will called!
print(test.member)
```

So this PyGetSetDef tp_getset can used for register each member with each get set function.
But i want to make RegisterFunction to register member to class with get set function.

This template need member pointer type and it's member's name.
I want to make each get set function per each member getset def by template.

```
template<typename MEMBER_POINTER_T, string memberName>
static PyObject* GetFunction(EPN_PyObject* _pSelf, void* _pClosure)
{
   //impl the get function
   //i need members name...
}

 //How should i use template to make Get Set Function
 //like below? 
 PyGetSetDef def[3] = 
 {
   {"X", GetFunction<&Position::X, "X"> , 
        SetFunction<&Position::X, "X">, nullptr},
   {"Y", GetFunction<&Position::Y, "Y"> , 
      SetFunction<&Position::Y, "Y">, nullptr},
    {0,0} 
 }
```

But The template only needs int constant or typename... it can not accept string.
How should i make each get set functions per member getsetdef?